# How to mark ContentNote as a requirements for the installation of the managed package

Tags: apex, managed-package

The Salesforce managed package I'm working on uses the record type `ContentNote`. This record type is available only when the Salesforce organization has enabled the enhanced version of notes.

Currently, if the Salesforce org does not have new notes enabled an error is thrown by Salesforce when the managed package is being installed. Could I set this as a requirement for the installation of the package? When I create the package there is a section called `Additional Object Requirements` but it does not contain the `ContentNote` object.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this at the point of package upload, but afaik the error will only be shown once you've installed, not before.

In the packaging org, go to your package, click Upload, then there is an option for Content and you can tick that as being required.

Then if Notes aren't enabled, on install you'll get the error: "Missing Organization Feature: ContentNote".

Comment: Thank you I will try next time I upload the package!

Comment: I have verified and I have already selected the `Content` option, I am not sure it refers to the enhanced notes features. When a Salesforce org without the feature enabled in their org tries to install the package they get a lot of errors with: ```Invalid type: ContentNote```

Comment: That's what that means. ContentNote is the API name for Notes. (This object gets created when you select Enable Notes)

Comment: Oh yes I knew that but I thought the user would get a better warning even before installing the package. Here it seems like Salesforce starts executing the tests and does not find the object because notes is not enabled, but the customer gets these very complicated error messages that he/she does not know what to do about. If this is the case, I am puzzled about the usefulness of marking a feature as required in the managed package as opposed to just let it try execute the tests and fail because no object with that name is found.